# For a site built on CodeIgniter that is already deployed, is there a way to know which PHP file on the view the generate the HTML of each page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently working on site built by another developer on CodeIgniter. I do not have the GitHub repository since there is no way to reach the previous developer. All I have now is the project files stored in the file system of the host. I found the view folder of the project and see a bunch of PHP files on it. The codes of each PHP files look similar, I am having trouble knowing which PHP files generate which page.

My question is, on the browser, is there a way to know which PHP files generate the HTML of the page that I am currently viewing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CodeIgniter, `Controllers` are the routes generally. Look in the controllers directory. For example `User` controller with `update` method will result in `/user/update` route. Moreover, the developer might have specified custom routes too. You will have to check `application/config/routes.php` too. Once you will locate the correct controllers, you can find the views used by the related controllers (or routes). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the "view" files to quickly figure out what URL displays that file. It's entirely possible that any given "view" file is used on multiple pages. It's also quite likely that any given URL will use multiple "view" files.

You should instead examine the files under `/application/controllers` and look for lines of code making a call to `$this->load->view('some_file_name_here');` There may or may not be a subdirectory as part of the file name - depends on how the original dev organized things.

The CodeIgniter documentation is excellent and is found [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html). Start with the [General Topics](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/index.html). In particular, the following general topics (in the order shown) may be highly useful and help you make sense of what the other answers are talking about.

1. Controllers
2. Views
3. CodeIgniter URLs
4. URI Routing
5. Models

A read-through of the [tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html) will be helpful too after checking out the above.

Use the [Libraries](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/index.html) section of the docs to get details on the various parts of the framework you're likely to run into in your explorations.